# CSS object1:hover object2 { change property }

Tags: css, hover, background-image, css-sprites

I think the title is the sum of everything...

I have a sprite image and over it another image (like an image frame). What I want is to move the lower image background to the given coordinates when the mouse hovers over the top image :/

In other words, I can't get the sprite to work while having another image over it.

Can anyone help?

this is direct link to my dev server so you can see:

kp77=mine=nu~pokop

= is ., and ~ is /

For now I have a solution with jquery, but I would like pure CSS only. I can't use inline :hover pseudo class so..

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe I don't understand the issue, but why not simple

```
a.fg:hover span:first-child {
    background-position: 0px 0px !important;
}
```

? Here is [the working CSS-only example](http://www.webdevout.net/test?0t), that, I assume, does what you want to achieve with JS

Comment: Any comments on why the down vote? Or people are too brave to click the button and shrink to comment on why?

Comment: @Mk Dizajn, does this solution do what you need or there is something I don't understand about the issue?

Comment: You used :first-child pseudo class, I used specific class names of spans, but what I was missing is "!important". Thanks again for your help

Answer (score -1):

look here [CSS: Animation Using CSS Transforms](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/css/css-animation/)

somtehing like this
Translated to the right:

```
a:hover
{
-webkit-transform: translate(3em,0);
 }
```

Firefox and Opera now support these transforms with an identical syntax. Just replace `-webkit` with `-moz` and/or -o in the examples and you will see the same effects

Comment: The question is not about animation at all in my opinion. Moreover CSS3 animations work only in webkit. And in addition, the code snippet you give, what is this? Is it CSS? Then, there are mistakes in it: pseudo-classes should not have spaces infornt, should not have colons after. And then, there is no 'onhover' pseudo-element at all in CSS

Comment: Firefox and Opera now support these transforms with an identical syntax. Just replace -webkit with -moz and/or -o in the examples and you will see the same effects